# If $\alpha,\beta \in BV[a,b]$, prove that $|a| \in BV[a,b]$ and $\min(\alpha,\beta),\max(\alpha,\beta) \in BV[a,b]$.

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

**Question:**

If $\alpha,\beta \in BV[a,b]$, prove that $|a| \in BV[a,b]$ and $\min(\alpha,\beta),\max(\alpha,\beta) \in BV[a,b]$.

**Attempt:**

Since $\alpha \in BV[a,b]$,
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \left| \alpha(x_i) - \alpha(x_{i-1}) \right| \leq V_a^b \alpha. $$
By the triangle inequality, we have
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \left| |\alpha(x_i)| - |\alpha(x_{i-1})| \right| \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \left| \alpha(x_i) - \alpha(x_{i-1}) \right| \leq V_a^b \alpha $$
so $|\alpha| \in BV[a,b]$. For the second part, we have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n \left| \min( \alpha_i - \alpha_{i-1},\beta_i - \beta_{i-1}) \right| &< \sum_{i=1}^n \left( |\alpha(x_i) - \alpha(x_{i-1})| + |\beta(x_i) - \beta(x_{i-1})| \right) \\
&\leq V_a^b \alpha + V_a^b \beta.
\end{align*}
and similarly
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n \left| \max( \alpha_i - \alpha_{i-1},\beta_i - \beta_{i-1}) \right| &< \sum_{i=1}^n \left( |\alpha(x_i) - \alpha(x_{i-1})| + |\beta(x_i) - \beta(x_{i-1})| \right) \\
&\leq V_a^b \alpha + V_a^b \beta.
\end{align*}
Hence, $\min(\alpha,\beta),\max(\alpha,\beta) \in BV[a,b]$.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: Yes. And also the combination of locally lipschitz function with BV function is BV and this is also hold in muti-dim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is correct. Another, lazier approach: after proving that $|\alpha|\in BV$ use the identities 
$$
\max(\alpha,\beta)= \frac12 (\alpha+\beta+|\alpha-\beta|)
$$
$$
\min(\alpha,\beta)= \frac12 (\alpha+\beta-|\alpha-\beta|)
$$
together with the fact that BV is a linear space.

Comment: This is clever. Mine seems like the lazy version of this approach!